# Matlab: generate a controlled random vector

Tags: matlab, random, vector

I am trying to generate a random vector of integer with the following caractetistics:

```
min(V) = my_min; max(v) = my_max;
If I suppose to divide the vector in some intervals, e.g.:
V = [my_min, v1, v2, v3,...,my_max];
first interval is my_min, v1;
second one interval is v1,v2
etc
```

I would to generate a different number of values beetwen each interval and each interval must have only unique values.
I thought  **randperm** but I can't define the minimum and maximum interval e.g. V1 V2 
For example, I would get the following vector where

```
my_min = 0;
my_max = 65;
V1 = 10;
V2 = 20;
V3 = 50;
V4 = 60;
V = [0 1,2,5 10, 13,14, 20,25,45,46,48,50,55,56,58, 60,61,62,65]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `randperm` will do, just shift the result.

I will try to write the code:

```
nodeValues = [0, 10, 20];
numRandNumbers = [7, 6];

for ii = 2:length(nodeValues)
  randNumArray{ii - 1} = nodeValues(ii - 1) + randperm((nodeValues(ii) - nodeValues(ii - 1)), numRandNumbers(ii - 1));
end
```

This will do the work.
Pay attention, I wrote the code out of my mind, It might need some revising.

Comment: Ok, the code generate a randNumArray cell of two matrices. randNumArray = [1x7 double]    [1x6 double] How can I do to obtain only one vector,in this case,as a cell sorted? Thank you